# Is it possible to install two MFP servers on one machine?

Tags: websphere-liberty, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I was wondering if its possible to set up two MFP servers on one machine?
Use one for testing and one for staging(kind of a pre-production).

I found a on IBM docs that they describe how to run multiple servers in MFP studio, but can't seem to find anything multiple MFP servers on WebSphere  Application Server liberty Profile (WAS-LP).

If it is possible, does it require a second installation:

```
2nd WAS-LP + 
2nd MFP + 
Create 2nd MFP server + 
Install 2nd Appcenter 
New config and 
A runtime? 
with it's own database ? or just tables? with custom names.
```

Or would it be better to have a single instance of WAS-LP and the Appcenter 
and simply create a new config call it dev? and add runtimes.

Many thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Theoretically, it should be possible to have a single WAS LP installation with 2 server.xml's that you will swap between them. This single application server will have the various .war files and other resources of both MFP servers and its artifacts deployed. To me, this is kinda dirty and not as-easy to manage.

You could also have two separate WAS LP installations, each with its own setup.
For the sake of sanity and clearness, I would opt to having two application server installations. But that's really a personal preference thing.

Comment: Understood, many thanks as always. I am sure I will be posting my experience trying it out :)

Comment: Was thinking about your post and thought I should ask what do you mean by swap them around? Do I need a proxy or some sort of NAT?

Comment: In case of one application server for both I don't think you can run both servers at the same time, so different server.xml for each mfp instance. Maybe you can, never tried...

Answer (score 1):

Each Liberty Profile instance, that is each server.xml, is independent, with its own set of working directories. You are (cough) at liberty to run several different servers for different purposes, starting and stopping them independently - this is why the

```
server start <servername>
```

takes that servername parameter. You do, of course, need to take care that the servers do not clash, they must be configured to use their own ports, working directories etc.

When deploying MFP/Worklght to a specific server you specify some MFP specific configuration, add WAR files etc. You can reasonably set up completely different MFP servers, perhaps running different versions of your application for different testing phases. In my case I wanted to explore some clustering behaviours and set up two servers as part of of a cluster, not a realistic scenario for production but useful for my testing as I only have one computer. This allowed me to configure a MFP server farm both of whose members happened to be on the same machine. In fact we went further and also ran one MFP server and two analytic server instances all on the same machine.

Comment: Good day, means I still can install 2 mfp into 1 liberty profile, but I cant access both mfp console at the same time?

Comment: @PanadolChong I'm sorry that I don't know the answer. I was not considering two instances in same server, I have not tried this and don't know whether it would work. I was considering the case of two instances on the same machine, each in their own server.